# Configuring Maven for Windows 7, Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23"" was unexpected at this time error

Tags: maven, windows-7, configure

I am trying to configure Maven on my Win 7 machine. I am following these steps:
http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi
I downloaded Maven into folder 
c:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.0.5\

I set all environmental variables as described in the URL above

```
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23
M2_HOME = c:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.0.5\
M2 = %M2_HOME%\bin
PATH = %M2%; C:\Program Files (x86)\SSH Communications Security\SSH Secure Shell;     %JAVA_HOME%\bin ; C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23
```

But when I enter:
C:\Users\Andrei>mvn --version

I get a :

Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23"" was unexpected at this time.

Can you please help me with this issue?
Let me know please if you need more details.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What did you enter, and what did you get? its unclear in your question.

Comment: changed description. It all happens in the command line

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This one solved it for me: http://www.xinotes.net/notes/note/559/

It is a problem with how the JAVA_HOME path is being set.

Set the path without quotes like this:

```
set java_home=c:\Program Files\Java
```

Or using the 8 char syntax for folder names like this:

```
set java_home="c:\Progra~1\Java"
```

Comment: Similarly, if you M2_HOME has quotes e.g. M2_HOME="C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.0.5"  then you will get the error: Files was unexpected at this time."

Comment: I was getting the "unexpected file" error and I sorted the issue with the link provided - it changed to **xinotes.net**
Maven does not like that the Windows variables are between double quotes with spaces:
This works: C:\Progra~2\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\
This doesn't: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_79"

Comment: @Cbaldan Thank you so much, man! That is such a stupid fix haha

Answer (score 2):

To solve the same issue

I did:

```
SET M2_HOME=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.2.3-bin\apache-maven-3.2.3
```

Then

```
SET JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7
```

And finally I added to the beginning of Path

```
SET Path=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%M2_HOME%\bin;...
```

After exiting all my running cmd.exe and opened a new one I was able to do *mvn --version* with no problems.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but the cause was M2_HOME variable defined as:

```
C:\apache-maven-3.2.2\bin
```

instead of

```
C:\apache-maven-3.2.2\
```

Also the JAVA_HOME should be to the java folder, and not to the \bin sub-folder.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue and the problem is with the presence of character "(" in the current directory path where maven is being run eg:- ***C:\Work(test)\Java-Project***. I simply changed it to ***C:\Work\Java-Project*** and its working fine now.

For info I'm running Windows 10 with Maven V3.6.0

Answer (score 0):

Insert with windows GUI Environment Variable Configurations > System Variables :
Name JAVA_HOME
Path C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\   << with "\" in the end. no quotes.

kill process cmd.exe and re-open if it was opened.
It worked to me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I didn't have quotes around the values for M2_HOME or JAVA_HOME, but still got the error.

I moved %M2_HOME%\bin and %JAVA_HOME%\bin left in the path so that both occurred before any spaces in the path and the problem vanished.

Answer (score 0):

> Error Message :  was unexpected at this time when I run mvn --version command in cmd.

Please find the procedure:

My Computer -> Right click properties-> Advanced-Environment Variables- User Variable

**Maven 3.2.3**

```
User Variable :
Variable name :M2 
Variable Value : %M2_HOME%\bin
Variable name : M2_HOME
Variable Value :  C:\WLS1033\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.2.3
Variable name :path 
Variable Value : %M2_HOME%\bin
```

Result :

```
D:\Documents and Settings\x169810>mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.2.3 (33f8c3e1027c3ddde99d3cdebad2656a31e8fdf4; 2014-08-11T16:58:10-04:00)
Maven home: C:\WLS1033\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.2.3
Java version: 1.6.0_18, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: C:\WLS1033\jdk160_18\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows xp", version: "5.1", arch: "x86", family: "windows"
```

My Computer -> Right click properties-> Advanced-Environment Variables- User Variable

**Maven 1.0.2**

```
User Variable :
Variable name :M2 
Variable Value : %MAVEN_HOME%\bin
Variable name : MAVEN_HOME
Variable Value :  C:\WLS1033\Apache Software Foundation\maven-1.0.2
Variable name :path 
Variable Value : %MAVEN_HOME%\bin
```