# Maven - "files was unexpected at this time"

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to install maven to my PC.(windows 7)

Following are the steps I have done.

```
1. Installed Java 1.8.0.11
2. Added a system variable JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11
3. Appended it to the path -  PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\Program Files\......;... etc
4. Typed "Java -version" in command line and got the java version details as usual.
5. Then I downloaded and extracted the Maven 3.3.3 
6. Added the M2_HOME to system variable.M2_HOME=C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.3\apache-maven-3.3.3
7. Added M2 Variable  M2=%M2_HOME%\bin
8. Appended M2 to Path variable. PATH=%M2%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;....;...etc
9. Typed mvn --version in command line.
```

Get the following error.

> Files was unexpected at this time.

What is wrong here?
Please help me to get this resolved.

Thanks in advance!

**Note - I have not use quotes for any of the paths here. also I tried with 8 char syntax for folder names like this:

set java_home="c:\Progra~1\Java"

Non of these were resolved the issue. Please read the steps I have added and help me to get this resolved.**

Comment: `%M2_HOME%\bin` should be added to `PATH` like what you did with Java.

Comment: And you don't need M2 and M2_HOME actually.

Comment: @Tunaki Some tools provide out-of-the-box integrations if they find `M2_HOME`.

Comment: @nobeh Oh. Which ones?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configuring Maven for Windows 7, Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\_23"" was unexpected at this time error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15392191/configuring-maven-for-windows-7-files-java-jdk1-6-0-23-was-unexpected-at-this)

Comment: @Gergely I tried it too, and all the path I have set are without quotes.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Finally I was able to resolved the issue.

A quoted value in the user variables has caused to the "Files were unexpected at this time" error in maven.

I spent hours of time with changing Java_home and M2_home variables with different combinations but finally checked the user variable and noted the quotes there.

```
Home = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin"
```

Removed the quotes and change the git home variable as below and now all works fine. :)

```
Home = C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin
```

[image: This is where the error was]

Comment: You get the same problem if the `JAVA_HOME` value has quotes

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue 
`Files\apache-maven-3.3.9""=="" was unexpected at this time.`
 and when looking at "Environment Variables" inside "System Properties" there were no quotes (") inside of any variables, but before doing that I was following a tutorial and set those values via cmd: 
 `C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin>set M2_HOME="C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.9"`

So, in order to fix it I just re-run the following in cmd:

`C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin>set M2_HOME=C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.9`
 (removed " from cmd assignment) I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.3\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin
```

to `PATH` variable

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue in `jenkins` when I asked jenkins to install `maven` internally. 
Notice double quotes below when `jenkins` was firing a build

```
 '""C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\tools\hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation\maven\bin\mvn.cmd"' -f ./Voyager/pom.xml clean package....
```

**To resolve this I downloaded maven and manually set the path in jenkins and it was resolved.**