# Google Cloud SDK Installation Error: Files was unexpected at this time

Tags: windows-10, google-cloud-sdk

I tried to install the Google Cloud SDK for Windows using this documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart

It fails during the installation on Windows 10 Pro.  Here is what the log says:

**Files was unexpected at this time.**

**Failed to install.**

I have tried installing using the installer and also installing using Powershell.  I have also tried installing Python 3.8 first and then unchecking the Bundled Python option.  Nothing works, it is all the same error above.

Comment: Smells similar to this ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34631826/maven-files-was-unexpected-at-this-time ... see if any of your environment variables have quotes in their values.

Comment: Good idea.  I do not have any environment variables with quotes in them.

Comment: how are you installing? are you following the [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-windows)

Comment: I am following the instructions provided by Google in the original question.  The quickstart link provided does not help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue that is being tracked [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/146458519)

As a workaround you can do the following:

1) Uninstalled python37 and windows python launcher.

2) Re-installed python37 and re-added to the environment Path variable (This re-instated my missing python.exe file also; the py.exe file is also in it's Windows location for python launcher)

3) Deleted all previous SDK folders/files.  (There was one still hanging out there from my previous copy)

4) Re-downloaded SDK and UNCHECKED the python bundle checkbox.  It gave me a warning message that python was not installed, but after it completed, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

- Uninstall python and google cloud sdk.
- Download and install stable version of python at other location like 
  D:/python.exe
- Set environment variable
- Re-install Google cloud sdk.