# How to run apdutool from command line?

Tags: eclipse, environment-variables, javacard

I am trying to run a java card project. I have installed all the required plugins.

I am running windows in virtual machine in my macbook.

When I try to run the apdutool command from the command prompt:

I see the error:

```
'C:\Program' is not recognised as an internal command or external command,operable program or batch file.
```

And then I changed the **JAVA_HOME** and **JC_HOME** variables to the following:

```
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_71\bin

JC_HOME   = C:\Users\MrT\Downloads\java_card_kit-2_2_2-windows\java_card_kit-2_2_2\java_card_kit-2_2_2-rr-bin-windows-do\bin
```

**Step 1:**

As suggested in the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845809/c-program-is-not-recognized-error), I included the path in quotes:

now, I set the environment variables as:

```
JAVA_HOME = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_71\bin"

JC_HOME   = "C:\Users\MrT\Downloads\java_card_kit-2_2_2-windows\java_card_kit-2_2_2\java_card_kit-2_2_2-rr-bin-windows-do\bin"
```

And when I try to run the apdutool command, I got the error:

```
Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_71\bin"" was unexpected at this time.
```

Note: I am running the command from the folder:

```
 C:\Users\MrT\Downloads\java_card_kit-2_2_2-windows\java_card_kit-2_2_2\java_card_kit-2_2_2-rr-bin-windows-do\bin>  apdutool
```

I am not sure wether to set the environment variable as **JAVA_HOME** or **%JAVA_HOME%** .

System variable **Path** is set as:

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
```

User variable **Path** is set as:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_71\bin
```

**Step 2:**

As suggested in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15392191/configuring-maven-for-windows-7-files-java-jdk1-6-0-23-was-unexpected-at-this):

I set the java_home like this:

```
    set java_home=c:\Program Files\Java
```

and then I try to run the command:

I got the error:

```
MrT\Downloads\java_card_kit-2_2_2-windows\java_card_kit-2_2_2\java_card_kit-2_2_2-rr-bin-windows-do\bin"" was unexpected at this time.
```

also tried this:

```
    set java_home="c:\Program Files\Java"
```

and I got error:

```
   Files\Java"" was unexpected at this time.
```

**Step 3:**

When I use single quotes to set the path in environment variables, I get the error:

```
   The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
```

**Step 4:**

I also tried adding % wherever there is a space in the path:

```
    set java_home="c:\Program%Files\Java"
```

and then it gave me the error:

```
    The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Can someone assist me in solving the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened the **apdutool** in word document, and found:

```
if not "%JAVA_HOME%" == "" goto check_tool
    echo Please set the JAVA_HOME environment variable
 goto end
```

and I removed the double quotes around %JAVA_HOME%:

```
 if not %JAVA_HOME% == "" goto check_tool
    echo Please set the JAVA_HOME environment variable
 goto end
```

I did the same for JC_HOME

and the error was gone.

Comment: The previous error was solved . No , it's not working . I am getting unable to load class sun. Javacard.main error.

Comment: After adding the bin in the JC_HOME path, the tool worked fine.@Abraham

Comment: i did the same but it's not working i'm getting (Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221 was unexpected at this time. )